# Is there a formula for the inverse of Hadamard product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product

Say $A$ and $B$ are two square, positive-semidefinite matrices. Is there an expression in terms of matrix product, transpose, and inverse for the Hadamard product $A∘B$?

For example, "$(A∘B)^{-1} = A^{-1} ∘ B^{-1}$" (which is not true).

Edit: I understand that $A∘B$ may not be invertible, but is there any expression if invertibility is given?

Comment: Formulas exist for the transpose (T), complex (*) and hermitian (H) conjugates as well as the element-wise inverse ($\Theta$) of a Hadamard product 
$$\eqalign{
(A&\circ&B)^T &= A^T&\circ&B^T \\
(A&\circ&B)^* &= A^*&\circ&B^* \\
(A&\circ&B)^H &= A^H&\circ&B^H \\
(A&\circ&B)^\Theta &= A^\Theta&\circ&B^\Theta \\
}$$
but sadly there is no formula for the standard matrix inverse.

Answer (score 5):

There won't be such a formula. In fact, if $A$ and $B$ are invertible, we can't guarantee that $A\circ B$ will even have an inverse.  In particular, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
we note that $A=A^{-1}$ and $B = B^{-1}$, but $A\circ B = 0$.

---

It is often, however, useful to consider the Hadamard product as a submatrix of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  For the Kronecker product, we have
$$
(A \otimes B)^{-1} = A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}
$$

Comment: I sort of ask this question because I know Kronecker product has this property and Hadamard product is a submatrix of Kronecker product, but a similar equation is not true.

Comment: Ah.  Well, in general, you can't find the inverse of a submatrix in terms of the inverse of the overall matrix.

Comment: Hi, how can I prove that $A^{-1}\circ B^{-1}\ge (A\circ B)^{-1}$ ? Is it true that proving $A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}\ge (A\otimes B)^{-1}$ is enough?

Comment: @Fareed I don't know what you mean by $\geq$ in this context and anyway I don't happen to know the answer off the top of my head.  Please make a new post about your question if you're interested in an answer.

Comment: I mean by $\ge$, if $A\ge B$ i.e. $A-B\ge 0$ then $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @FareedAbiFarraj I still don't know.  We can get $A^{-1} \circ B^{-1}$ as a submatrix of $A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$, but I see no way to get $(A \circ B)^{-1}$ by extracting a submatrix.

Answer (score 4):

The Hadamard (aka element-wise) inverse $A^{\theta}$ is such that $A\circ A^\theta = 1$.

If any element of $A$ is zero, then the Hadamard inverse is undefined.

It satisfies a product rule similar to that of the Kronecker product, i.e. 
$$ (A\circ B)^\theta = A^\theta\circ B^\theta $$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.
If $A$ is invertible,
and
$B_{i, j}
=1/A_{i,j}
$,
then
$B$ is also invertible
but
$A∘B$
is all ones
and therefore
not invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think there is a formula for that, in terms of the Hadamard inverse of the first matrix and the inverse of the second one. For example, if:

$\Sigma = A \circ B$

then the inverse of $\Sigma$ can be written as:

$\Sigma^{-1} = A^{\circ (-1)} \circ B^{-1}$

where $A^{\circ (-1)}$ is the Hadamard inverse of $A$, which is defined as

$[A^{\circ (-1)}]_{i,j} = 1/[A]_{i,j}$

Thus B must be invertible, and if $\Sigma$ is invertible as well (as in your question), it follows that $A^{\circ (-1)}$ is well defined.

Also, a sufficient though not necessary condition is then that $B$ and $A$ be invertible, as [Reams](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379598101623) proofs that if $A$ is invertible then $A^{\circ (-1)}$ is positive definite.

Comment: Is there a proof for the equation of $\Sigma^{-1}$ given?

Comment: Just tried this numerically and it seems to be incorrect...

Comment: Seems to hold for symmetric rank one A.

Comment: This method works for all $1\times 1$ matrices $A,B$ such that $A_{1,1},B_{1,1}\neq 0$, since $I_1=\left(1\right)$