# Inverse of a sum of special matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, closed-form

Does anyone know of any tricks to evaluate the following inverse of matrix sums?

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^m D_i A D_i \right)^{-1} $$

where the $D_i$ are non-singular diagonal matrices, and $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix common to all terms in the sum. All these matrices are square and $n \times n$. I would like to find a closed form solution to this matrix inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing a bit,

$${\bf B} := \sum_{i=1}^d \mbox{diag} ({\bf v}_i) \, {\bf A} \,\mbox{diag} ({\bf v}_i) = \sum_{i=1}^d {\bf v}_i {\bf v}_i^\top \circ {\bf A} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^d {\bf v}_i {\bf v}_i^\top \right) \circ {\bf A} = \left( \, {\bf V} {\bf V}^\top \right) \circ {\bf A} $$

where $\circ$ denotes the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) and ${\bf V}$ is the $n \times d$ matrix whose $i$-th column is ${\bf v}_i$. The inverse of ${\bf B}$ can be computed using standard methods.

---

- [Is there a formula for the inverse of Hadamard product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1321879/339790)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems, according to the other article you linked, there is no expression for the inverse of the Hadamard product